# SEARCH and SUBSTITUTE Multiple value

Tags: excel, substitution

Column D is result of LOOKUP from Column C

```
   A       B       C          D
1 1234   1234567   Person1   ASKXXXXXXXX
2 3692   8465837   Person2   AFTXXXX
```

I need to replace X's in D with B if there are 8 of them,
and to replace X's in D with A if there are 4X's.

I tried formula below, but only works for 8X's, not with 4X's.

```
    =IF(SEARCH("XXXXXXXX",D2),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXXXXXX",$B$2),IF(SEARCH("XXXX",D2),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXX",$A$2),""))
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `SEARCH` fails you get `#VALUE!` as the result. The `IF` formula doesn't know how to deal with this so it fails.

You need to write your formula to handle errors. Do this:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("XXXXXXXX",D2))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXXXXXX",$B$2),IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("XXXX",D2))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXX",$A$2),D2))
```

Comment: How to deal with no X's?

Comment: @silver_river - Put `D2` in the place of the `""` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This works on your provided data

```
=LEFT(TRIM(D2),3)&IF(LEN(RIGHT(TRIM(D2),LEN(TRIM(D2))-3))=4,A2,B2)
```

Comment: Much appreciated your answer. Forgot to say that cells either 8X's, 4X's or non. If I use LEFT, problem with no X's